# Is there any proof that there doesn't exist a Hadamard matrix of size $6 \times 6$?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, hadamard-matrices

A matrix $H \in {\pm 1}^n $ is Hadamard matrix if $HH^T=nI_n$, where $I$ is $n\times n$ identity matrix. Hadamard's conjecture said that there exists Hadamard matrix of order 1,2 or $4n$, for every positive integer $n$.

My question is **how to prove there does not exists a $6 \times 6$ Hadamard matrix**?

Comment: An interesting and well written document on Hadamard matrices (in general ; your issue isn't addressed strictly speaking) : https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/9898/thesis_revised.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 9):

Wlog (why?) the first row is $(1\,1\,1\,1\,1\,1)$ and all other rows have  three $+1$ and three $-1$ entries. If the second and third row have $r$ entries $+1$ in common ($0\le r\le 3$), then they also have $r$ entries $-1$ in common and their scalar product is $r\cdot 1^2+r\cdot (-1)^2+(6-2r)\cdot(-1)=4r-6\ne0$, contradiction.

---

Upon closer look, this argument can be extended to show that $H_n$ can exist *only* when $4\mid n$ or $n<3$:

Assume $n\ge 3$. Again with the first row being wlog all-ones, every other row must have an equal amount of $+1$'s and $-1$'s, hence $n$ must be even. Then as above, if the second and third row have $r$ entries $+1$ in common, they also share $r$ entries $-1$, and their scalar product is $4r-n$. As this is $0$, it follows that $4\mid n$.

Comment: [+1] Very interesting proof